# Last element in ngfor causes ng100:expression has changed after

Tags: angular, ngmodel, two-way-binding

I use [(ng model)] for a property in a ng for. I need a two-way data binding since I need to update the property and display its new value.
For some reason the last element causes ng100 error. So, if I add another element to the list, the second last element does not cause the ng100 error anymore.
Does someone know why the last index would always cause this ng100 error of changed after...
The line that is causing it it [(ng model)]
=item.params

I have tried to use [ng model] instead and then use event but that did not sort it out.
I have also.tried this.cdRef.detectChanges() and it did not work since then I could not change the input at all.
My HTML looks like below. My ts file has no code related to this.

```
<div *ngFor="let items of items; 
index as i;>
<form>
<div *ngif="show(i)">
<input[(ngmodel)] ="item.params" 
 name="params">
<\div>
<\form>
<\div>
```

Comment: could you  share the code where that is hapenning?

Comment: Hey I have edited it with the htm page. In my ts file nothing is stated regarding this.

Comment: Please add the typescript file. This error is correlated to your model. Without the typescript code we will not be able to find out what is causing this error.

Comment: My typescript file does not do anything with the params variable at all.

Answer (score 0):

The [ng100](https://angular.io/errors/NG0100) is a common issue faced by many beginners who don't completely understand how change detection works. Regarding your issue, it would help if you showed the code as well. But in general, you can make use of one-way binding **[ngModel]** instead of using two-way binding **[(ngModel)]**.

and in your loop make use of the (ngModelChange) event handler.

eg

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <input [ngModel]="item.name" (ngModelChange)="yourMethod($event,i)">
</div>
```

[Change detection](https://indepth.dev/posts/1001/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error)

Comment: Thanks I have tried this, but then the input file does not show the current value when you refresh the page.

Comment: refresh the page? You mean the input field? Yes, it won't show the current value it will be reset. Why do you need to refresh the page? Angular is a single page application, in general it is not recommended to do it.

Comment: I made an error earlier, but I did try your code, but I get the same result. Now for every item I get the error.